# What is the purpose of putting Assertions. prefix?

Tags: java, assertion

My question is regarding the assert methods because I am curious about the difference between the following practices in java. In unit tests when using assertion some cases `Assertions` prefix had used and but some had not!

With Assertion prefix

```
Assertions.assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,() -> {
            Validationclass.validationMethod(Request);
        });
```

Without the prefix

```
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class,() -> {
                Validationclass.validationMethod(Request);
            });
```

So, my questions are,

1. What is the purpose of adding the prefix?
2. Is there any adding advantage of doing so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: second one is possible using static imports, where you can import static fields and functions of another class. Static fields/functions are class assets and does not required to create new class instance to use them.

Comment: Very basic but deep question.

Answer (score 3):

Being explicit about the class, style and keeping the `static` namespace clear to enable another (local) method named [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows-java.lang.Class-org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable-). Basically, someone has to `import` the static reference for the second form to work. Other than being slightly less verbose when typing, they are identical.

See also [Static Import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If we are coding in version control what form from the above is most appropriate?

Comment: @UpaniK Version control is irrelevant to the topic at hand. It's a matter of style, pick one and use it (and this should be limited to unit tests anyway). Also, **if** you are coding in version control? You should **A̳L̳W̳A̳Y̳S̳** code in version control.

Answer (score 1):

JUnit Tests without `Assertions` would require more boilerplate. while `assertThrows` without JUnit would require you to write a whole framework.

Comment: In version control what is the best way from the above? Use the prefix or not? Or is there no any difference?

Comment: I suggest to use `Assertions.assertThrows` as it adds all the boilerplates to my tests internally which can be used further after years without the fear of which version the system is currently on.

Comment: Thankyou so much! It makes sense now!